# Importing a vector file into Photoshop WITHOUT rasterising it

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, import

I have a simple question: How do I import a vector file into Photoshop WITHOUT getting it rasterised?

I know that Photoshop can do curves and paths and all of that, so why can't I open an SVG file in it?

I have now tried everything I can. I have a perfectly fine, vector imagine in one PDF file, now I want it to be transferred to Photoshop so it can have the vectors preserved. You cannot tell me it's impossible.

Answer (score 5):

Photoshop can import an SVG file as a "[smart object](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/create-smart-objects.html)". Although you will not be able to edit the curves so to speak (Photoshop is not a vector editing program...Illustrator is) the image will not be rasterised, and is fully scalable and non-destructively editable.

Chose File  > Place Embedded (or Place Linked). Double click to edit the contents of the Smart Object (the SVG file in Illustrator). Or you can drag and drop an SVG from the libraries panel.

Answer (score 4):

You can cut and paste vector shapes to Photoshop from Illustrator. You have two options available to paste as a vector which is editable with Photoshop's vector tools:

- paste as shape layer
- paste as path

**ADD**: see a comment. Smart object also keeps the vector data, but it's not editable in PS. You can open it in Illustrator.

Lets' have the following image in illustrator:

[image]

Pasted to Photoshop they are:

[image]

The upper is pasted as shape layer. It generated a layer filled with the current foreground color and masked with all paths what happened to be included. You can make edits with the white arrow tool. Text is outlined, no more a text object.

The lower is pasted as path. Every path was added to the work path as new sub-paths. They can be selected, edited, stroked or used to make selections.

If you expect how to import it to PS as is with all colors, strokes effects and as fully in Photoshop editable vector, you must import it shape by shape to build the new layers with right colors. You will not get colors, strokes nor effects as vectors, only zero width colorless paths. The rest must be rebuilt in PS.

Comment: You have 3 options: paste as a smart object. It will still be a vector object inside Photoshop, albeit not editable (in Photoshop - you can always open it back in Illustrator from the layers panel)

Comment: The new version of Photoshop offers four options to paste SVG files from Illustrator:
1. Smart Object 2. Pixels 3. Path 4. Shape Layer

Answer (score 1):

Simply put: Photoshop is **not** a vector editor.

Photoshop merely has *some* vector editing capabilities in it's **raster** code base but is not designed to be a full-fledged vector editing application.

If you wish to edit SVG files, a *more apprpriate* tool would be an *actual* vector editor such as Illustrator or InkScape. Or.... even a text editor to alter the SVG XML is more appropriate  than Photoshop.

- [How to create vector graphics In Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17865/how-to-create-vector-graphics-in-photoshop)
- [Is a Photoshop EPS file a vector format?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7726/is-a-photoshop-eps-file-a-vector-format)
- [Can Photoshop be used for vector purposes?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/96/can-photoshop-be-used-for-vector-purposes)
- [Why Illustrator if I have Photoshop shapes? Why Ai at all?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/85543/why-illustrator-if-i-have-photoshop-shapes-why-ai-at-all)

Comment: just because that's not the main thing it's designed for doesn't mean it's not a vector editor. it can edit vector shapes, therefore it is a vector image. not everyone has access to photoshop AND illustrator. IMO it's vector editing tools are much easier to use than any vector-specific tool, and so I'd much rather use photoshop to edit them.

Comment: clearly posted by someone unfamiliar with Illustrator trying to justify the use of Photoshop.

Comment: clearly posted by someone who has the money and time to throw away on extra programs. I do not want to use illustrator. it is much more confusing to learn. i do not want to learn a second program when photoshop already has all the tools i need and is easier to understand.

Comment: You don't seem to understand that Photoshop, while an excellent application, does **not** do everything. Check the links about.. you **can't** save a viable non-raster, vector-only file from Photoshop. Other than simple SVGs Photoshop is *incapable* of saving vector files. - I do get the money aspect.. but a carpenter isn't trying to build houses with ONLY a screwdriver. You need more than one tool in most instances. It makes no difference to me if you ONLY want to use Photoshop for everything but don't pretend Photoshop does everything, or everything well. It doesn't.

Comment: well a hobbyist carpenter probably isnt building houses.